# Sort query in luamongo

Tags: mongodb, sorting

I'm using [luamongo](https://github.com/moai/luamongo) to query mongodb. I'm quite inexperienced with mongodb, and I'm having trouble figuring out how to specify the sorting/order for the query. I don't see anything specifically about sorting on the [project's wiki](https://github.com/moai/luamongo/wiki), but I might be missing something.

Is there a way to do this, or do I need to manually sort the returned results?
Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/moai/luamongo/issues/14

Comment: Thanks; don't know why I didn't find that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://github.com/moai/luamongo/issues/14:

To sort a query: `mongodb:query("database.collection", {query = {field=value}, orderby = {field = 1}})`